# Effect when all html elements are set to inherit

Tags: css

I found this in our codebase:

```
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

It's causing me some immediate problems, but it raised the question for me--if *everything* is set to inherit something... what is the top-most level inheriting from?  Am I misunderstanding how the `*` operator works?

Comment: It would inherit from the root element, which is to say `html`. `html` doesn't inherit from anything.

Answer (score 1):

This rule just defines that all child elements will inherit the `box-sizing` setting from their parent element. So when you define a particular `box-sizing` for an element, all its children elements will have that same one, except where explicitly defined different.

If there are no `box-sizing` settings anywhere, everything will remain at the default setting, which is `content-box`.

Comment: So * means "all child-elements" not "all elements"?

Comment: * means all elements, but each one inherits from its parent, so if the setting is changed for one element, all its children will inherit that setting.